# How to plot real-time control charts on a web page using MySQL data and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, control-charts

I have real-time humidity and temperature data saved in a MySQL database. Now, I want to create a web page to monitor real time weather data in control charts. How do I plot real-time control charts on a web page using MySQL data and PHP?

Comment: Could you explain us what you have tryed so far so that we can help you to find a solution based on your current idea

Comment: I do not have great knowledge on web design or coding. But I have created login page with some tutorials and now I have no idea how to proceed. I have searched about this and I didn't get any idea about this. Data getting part is over. I have used NodeMCU and DTH sensor to get weather data. I have used 000webhost hosting site to store data and hosting. Now I want to design a web page which can monitor weather data in control chart (graph). I want some instructions and samples to do that task.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a client-side scripting language like Javascript to make ajax request to dynamically update the content of the page. PHP is a server side language and will not be able to do that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I’ll try with that.